# Web Components future proof

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm currently working on a new WebApp and excited about Web components and its opportunity to build a modular app. But on the other side there is the uncertainty whether the four parts of web Components become a cross browser standard. Mozilla recently announced, that they no longer work on html imports, webkit until now only supports templates and so on...

I know there are polyfills (e.g. webcomponents.js filling these gaps), but I have the task to develop an application which is future-proof, so I will using standards.

So my question: Can I use web components because they will become a standard certainly?

Comment: No one can predict the future...

Comment: That's true! But maybe someone can estimate how likely it is, that one of the specs will be discarded or how certain, that they becom standard some day.

Comment: You're asking for someones estimate - this is problematic because any answer will be 100% bound to the time/context in which the answer was posted. If there is some revelation tomorrow (or next week) that will change the current state of things, the provided answer will become invalid/obsolete.

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours

Comment: Despite the question seem too broad and primarily based on personal opinion, I think it's a good opportunity to expose updated arguments for and against Web Components. A lot of questions and material out there already are outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the question seem too broad and primarily based on personal opinion, I think it's a good opportunity to expose updated arguments for and against *Web Components*, to support a more rational decision-making.

First, as others already have said, *it's impossible to predict the future*, especially when it comes to technological changes. Even some officially recommended specification may be outdated in a few years as another even better emerge. So, before you make your decision, *you should ask yourself about the term of this future you intend to "predict"*.

On the *Web Components* itself, **there are no longer a single specification** (which was already [discontinued](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)), but [some smaller specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_Web_Components). In short, they are:

- [**HTML Templates**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-templates/): is the simplest part, already completed and [very broadly supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template). Curiously discontinued of the *Web Components* spec and became [part of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element).
- [**Shadow DOM**](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/): the most difficult spec to polyfill (until now, the most "ready" thing is the [Shady DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html)). I'm happy that it seems to be going to [an agreement](http://www.w3.org/2015/07/21-webapps-minutes.html) on how will it be standardized. As of December 2015, W3C still says the spec is for review, not for implementation.
- [**Custom Elements**](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/): while very important, the browsers developers still have many questions, especially when to activate a custom implementation along with the DOM loading. As of December 2015, W3C still says the spec is for review, not for implementation.
- [**HTML Imports**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/): are a Working Draft since March 2014 and seems to be very controversial because it overlaps a lot the [ECMAScript 6 module loading](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

I strongly recommend you to read more about it [in this nice blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/web-component-status.html) by [@Axel Rauschmayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717950/axel-rauschmayer) talking about what's happening with the *Web Components*, this can help you "predicting" a little better.

With all that said, *I personally pretend to stay away from Web Components for a while*, but I'll keep and eye on it, specially because of [Polymer Project](https://www.polymer-project.org/) claiming it's mature enough for production.

Comment: There is concrete movement on Shadow DOM too.  MS has marked the status of it as "Roadmap Priority: High — We intend to begin development soon" for Edge, and webkit's blog has announced "We’re pleased to announce that basic support for the new slot-based shadow DOM API we proposed in April is now available in the nightly builds of WebKit after r190680."  So, Shadow DOM now seems to be pretty much a sure thing for all the main browsers other then IE11.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with web components commercially for about 6 months now and I believe that the best way to write and make use of web components is by doing so using ES2015 (The next version of JavaScript). Not only is this easier to do it also means that you do not need to use HTML imports or HTML templates thanks to ES2015 template strings.

You will also be future proofing your web component code for when ES2015 becomes browser standard - you will need to transpile the ES2015 down to ES5 now using a few simple steps but will just be able to remove this step when ES2015 is available in all browsers.

If you would like to know more I think this article provides enough detail to show you how to quickly write web components using ES2015: http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/web-components-with-es2015-es6/

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know what will be standard in the future.  History has shown time and time again how a promising new technology got abandoned because late in the game there were problems in the fundamental design, or simply not enough adopters.  This has occurred with Microsoft, Google, Apple, and many others.

To design your application around technology that *might* become adopted as a standard is no way to future-proof your application.  For a long time, about a decade ago, Microsoft pushed VB Script as its answer to Javascript--and you would have been stuck rewriting your web site if you used VB Script.  Instead of building your application around a nifty new technology that "might" become generally adopted--you are better off building around a tried-and-true standard.

Answer (score 0):

***Web Components*** are a set of technologies. Each one with a different destiny:

**Template Element** is a W3C standard, part of the [HTML5 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element), and it is implemented in most modern browsers: Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

**Custom Elements** are now a WHATWG specification, part of the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements).
It is implemented in Chrome and Opera, Firefox and Edge (since 2020 with Chromium). On Safara only autonomous custum elements are implemented.

**Shadow DOM** is a WHATWG specification, part of the [DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadow-trees). Included in Chrome and Opera, Edge, Firefox and Safari. Since Shadow DOM are used by most browsers to display some special user controls (date, range, input...), it is likely to be maintained for a long time.

**HTML Imports (deprecated)** are [proposed by Google](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/) and were implemented in Chrome and Opera. They are now removed.

*Note:* There are polyfills ([Webcomponents.js](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) or [WebReflection](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element)) if you want a cross-browser compatibility.